# Java Spring Data Solr fails to create CRUD implementation - NPE in constructor

Tags: java, spring, solr

I get `Error creating bean with name 'classifierSolrRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`.

ClassifierSolrRepository class:

```
public interface ClassifierSolrRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<ClassifierSolr, String>
{   

    public List<ClassifierSolr> findByClassifierid(long id);

    public List<ClassifierSolr> findByLanguage(String language);

    public ClassifierSolr findByLanguageAndClassifierid(String language, long id);

    public ClassifierSolr findByLanguageAndCode(String language, String code);

}
```

ClassifierSolr class:

```
public class ClassifierSolr {


    @Field("id_s") 
    private String id;

    @Field("name_s")
    private String name;

    @Field("desc_s")
    private String desc;

    @Field("classifierid_l")
    private long classifierid;

    @Field("code_s")
    private String code;

    @Field("language_s")
    private String language;

    //getters and setters
    }
```

And finally my Solr configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableSolrRepositories("lt.gerasolutions.gsm.core.solrRepositories")
public class SolrContext {

      private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SERVER_URL = "solr.host";


      @Resource
      private Environment environment;

      @Bean 
      public SolrClient solrClient(){
          return new HttpSolrClient(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SERVER_URL));
      }

      @Bean 
      public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(){
          //return new SolrTemplate(solrClient(), "Classifiers");
          return new SolrTemplate(solrClient());
      }

}
```

The only reason I could see it failing, is due to mismatches of method names and fields, but it seems to no be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles into same problem - it didn't work because I had `solr-solrj / solr-core` as well as `spring-data-solr` maven dependencies. As soon as I removed everything but `spring-data-solr` (and changed `SolrClient` to `SolrServer` accordingly) it all started to work.